# Azure Application Insights | Performance filter configuration in Grafana

Tags: azure, variables, datasource, grafana

I'm trying to achieve the following : I want the Performance (page view urlhost) under Applications Insights to be displayed in Grafana. I connected Azure to Grafana and can pull through metrics but I want to filter on certain data, below is a screenshot from where I want the data.

[image]

I did add variables under the datasources and followed this link to add the variables : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/azuremonitor/

Any help or input would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue on my own.

I've gone through the metrics of the connected Azure Monitor service and got the specific metric I was looking for and then just set it to the metric I wanted.

Due to additional details in the screenshot I won't be able to share it but feel free to ask me for additional details.

Thanks.